# Как сделать нормальную автооплату?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Всем, привет. В общем у меня есть в телеграмм боте автооплата по киви, она все работает - все хорошо, до определенного момента. А именно, если ботом пользуются несколько человек и они одновременно пополняют баланс то бот крашится, т.к. все запутывается либо же у одного баланс не пополняется потому что код поменялся. В общем вопрос, как мне сделать автооплату при которой бот не будет крашится если пополняют несколько человек? Библиотека бота aiogram
Так же если у вас есть готовая автооплата такая я бы посмотрел как пример:) спасибо.

```
    elif call.data == 'bank_or_qiwi':
    random_code = randint(100000, 999999)
    code.append(random_code)
    bank_or_qiwi_sostoyanie.append(1)
    key_qiwi = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    otmena = InlineKeyboardButton('Оплатить', url=f'https://qiwi.com/payment/form/99?extra%5B%27account%27%5D={qiwi_number}&amountInteger={prices[-1]}&amountFraction=0&extra%5B%27comment%27%5D={code[-1]}&currency=643&blocked[0]=account')
    check = InlineKeyboardButton('⏳Проверить поступление', callback_data='check')
    key_qiwi.add(otmena).add(check).add(back)
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                text=f'Для оплаты нажмите кнопку "Оплатить", после чего нажмите на кнопку "Проверить"!', parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN,
                                reply_markup=key_qiwi)
    elif call.data == 'check':
    h = requests.get('https://edge.qiwi.com/payment-history/v1/persons/' + qiwi_number + '/payments?rows=50',
                     headers={'Accept': 'application/json',
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                              'Authorization': f'Bearer {qiwi_token}'})
    req = json.loads(h.text)
    for i in range(len(req['data'])):
        if req['data'][i]['comment'] == f"{code[-1]}":
            print(['data'][i])
            if req['data'][i]['sum']['amount'] == int(prices[-1]):
                await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Спасибо за покупку! Ссылка на канал: {chanell[-1]}')
                buy_tarifi.append(tarif[-1])
                break
        else:
            key_qiwi = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            otmena = InlineKeyboardButton('Оплатить',
                                          url=f'https://qiwi.com/payment/form/99?extra%5B%27account%27%5D={qiwi_number}&amountInteger={prices[-1]}&amountFraction=0&extra%5B%27comment%27%5D={code[-1]}&currency=643&blocked[0]=account')
            check = InlineKeyboardButton('⏳Проверить поступление', callback_data='check')
            key_qiwi.add(otmena).add(check).add(back)
            await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                        text=f'Платеж не был получен!', reply_markup=key_qiwi)
            break
```

Comment: Как вы предлагает помочь вам, не видя вашего кода? :) Добавьте пример кода. А так, у вас есть там база данных или используете простые коллекции?

Comment: База данных есть, а кусок кода для чего?) Тип там все хорошо работает по одном юзере а при нескольких сразу же крашится. Работает автооплата так: создаём ссылку на оплату с комментарием>даём эту ссылку пользователю с кнопкай проверки поступила ли оплата>при успешном поступлении пополняется баланс. Так теперь мне интересует как сделать так что бы если пользуются автооплатой несколько юзеров бот не крашнулся. Мне не нужно готовое решение, просто подсказка как такое реализовываться в больших ботах.

Comment: В таких вопросах как ваш принято: 1) добавить [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 2) добавить в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit]). Причин почему падает может быть куча и для этого минимум нужна трасса стека, чтобы увидеть текст ошибки, место и цепочку вызова, что привела к этому

Comment: @ИльяВетров Если все правильно реализовано, то бот не будет крашиться, очевидно, что у вас ошибка в реализации бота. Почему сейчас не работает без кода вам никто не скажет - мы не телепаты.

Comment: Добавил код автооплаты. Библиотека бота aiogram